# Is DWR a MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller, dwr

I started reading about [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) few days back. Its strikingly different from the usual web-app technologies I have worked on till date (read as huge amount of Struts). One question that invariably comes to mind is can DWR really replace MVC ?
One may argue about the usability of MVC but the more mature frameworks like Struts and JSF give lots of tools in the MVC. Validation, interpretors(struts2) etc..

From whatever I have understood about DWR from my little reading and if I can put it down in few words is that its nothing but say 'RPC over HTTP'. so, Can we really replace a MVC architecture with DWR ?

Comment: What's DWR? (15 chars needed)

Answer (score 2):

Like you say, DWR is basically "RPC over HTTP". It is a library that makes it easy to call (server-side) Java code from (browser-side) JavaScript. It does not replace a MVC architecture (it also does not require one), any more than a logging framework or JDBC replaces (or requires) a MVC architecture.